# How to solve "Unable to locate package"

Tags: unix, installation, terminal, cygwin, software-update

can you help me, i got this error when i use cygwin terminal

`$ apt-cyg install toilet`

> Installing toilet

> Unable to locate package toilet

Answer (score 0):

https://cygwin.com/packages/package_list.html

the package is not available on Cygwin.
Eventually you can try to build it by yourself, assuming that is feasible